# What's the proper why to create a secure ios authentication with my own server

Tags: iphone, ios, cakephp, authentication, lamp

From my understand, I have a LAMP system web server. I'm running Cakephp and using their Auth system.  How do I get my new ios app to authenticate correctly and securely with my web server.  I'm worried about hacking and security holes.

I have looked at Parse and others but to learn I want to build my own since part of it is done.

Comment: I added LAMP and Cakephp tags.  In general, you need to secure the communication channel using SSL.

Answer (score 1):

[Read about the security component](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html) and use it and enforce SSL for all pages related to users and passwords. Login, registration, password reset...

Further it might be a good idea to get a book about security if you don't have any idea. The quesiton is simply to broad to be answered within a reasonable amount of time. You want to read about XSS, CSRF. Also there is simple rule to folllow: *Never* trust data from foreign sources, no matter if its human made input or data coming from an API, *never* trust it. Always validate it and sanitize output as needed.